# Orders are not created when strategy.cash is used

Tags: pine-script

I want to test a strategy in Pinescript which uses arbitrary amount of cash to create orders. For example, buy 100 USD of S&P 500. Despite following the tutorial it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I'm using the following strategy definition:

`strategy("BarUpDn Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, currency=currency.USD, default_qty_value = 50, initial_capital = 1000, pyramiding = 9999)`

This means that when creating an order / going long, it should be using 50 USD as enter position. However, when if I have

`strategy.order("BarUp", strategy.long)`

Then when running the strategy I see no order being created in the Strategy Tester > List of Trades. Now if I add an explicit quantity, it uses the quantity as the Contract number, but not the cash number. e.g.

`strategy.order("BarUp", strategy.long,1)`

This results in an order getting created, but its 1 contract (4K usd for s&p 500) and not 1 USD, which is the quantity_type that my strategy defines.

This seems like an ultra basic use case but I'm not able to get it to work.

Full code snippet that should be able to reproduce the problem for any stock:

```
//@version=5
strategy("BarUpDn Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, currency=currency.USD, default_qty_value = 50, initial_capital = 1000, pyramiding = 9999)

// STEP 1. Create inputs that configure the backtest's date range
useDateFilter = input.bool(true, title="Filter Date Range of Backtest",
group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("1 Jan 2021"),
title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period",
tooltip="This start date is in the time zone of the exchange " +
"where the chart's instrument trades. It doesn't use the time " +
"zone of the chart or of your computer.")
backtestEndDate = input.time(timestamp("14 Nov 2022"),
title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period",
tooltip="This end date is in the time zone of the exchange " +
"where the chart's instrument trades. It doesn't use the time " +
"zone of the chart or of your computer.")

// STEP 2. See if current bar falls inside the date range
inTradeWindow = not useDateFilter or (time \>= backtestStartDate and
time \< backtestEndDate)

var currMonth = -1
var prevMonth = 0

if inTradeWindow
strategy.order("BarUp", strategy.long)
else
strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 1):

If `strategy.cash` is specified as the `default_qty_type`, then the `qty` value must be greater than the price of the security (close * syminfo.pointvalue).
Price of the security is more than 50$, so you should increase it.

`qty` parameter of the `strategy.order()` function specifies the number of contracts/shares/lots/units to trade (and redefines default strategy parameters) so it is not amout of cash, but number of contracts. If you want to override it, you can calculate number of contracts from the security price.

Comment: so youre saying theres no easy, fast way, for me to model a strategy in which I'm always buying X USD in cash from a given index?
That seems quite a common use case to support..
I always want to buy 100 USD or whatever. doesnt trading view support fractional shares / contracts?

Comment: >   If you want to override it, you can calculate number of contracts from the security price.

I tried but it doesn't accept fractional contracts. I don't understand why trading view doesn't allow me to model 'buy 100 USD of S&P500' when pretty much any broker allows me to buy an arbitrary amount of cash in a given stock. So I cannot model the strategy I want right now..

I want to model in trading view buying 100 USD of s&p500. How can I do that?